# Creating a Hyperlink in Google Sheets via formula

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have a been using a Calendar which populates the Data in Calendar by matching the dates from the Event Sheet and it is working fine.

One thing i want that the formula it should create a hyperlink on the value which is populated in the calendar so when i click on the cell it take me to the concern row of the event sheet.

I have quoted two examples. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(Events!$B:$B,Events!$C:$C<=B5,Events!$D:$D>=B5)))
```

Examples: [Hyperlink in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/hyperlink-to-index-match-output-in-google-sheets/) and [Gif](https://infoinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/index-match-hyperlink.gif)

Google Sheet Link [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yYFY90FjYpNexuZthA-u9AYhdN4oB37D9_VQNc5x8Kk/edit#gid=2044486134)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you create jump link:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=1102623837", Sheet2!A2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so there is no other way which can find the exact cell automatically via using formula/script. Because i have whole year calendar which changes by months and weekdays.  If i apply this way i have to work manually a lot.