# Using REGEXREPLACE to Populate the Data from Cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I have been using below formula which is working fine but i want to add one condition that is if data cell and the formula output result is same then it should add some comments with brackets as i did in `Col"C"`.

Any help towards the problem will be appreciated.

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"(\*{3}.*?)(?:\s*?\.{3}DONE=>.*)?(\*{3})$","$1 $2")))
```

[image]

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jd7AVAvHwfznW_tpykhJb58cPvE7BLxtnJCq9fZy0WE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why do you need to add  it here? Why not use something like `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A9=B2:B9, A2:A9 & " (No measure applicable)", B2:B9))` in Column C?

Comment: Because if i use the `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A9=B2:B9, A2:A9 & " (No measure applicable)", B2:B9))` its result would be like this `*** HEDAL - 2020 COMPLETE - IB - 06-01-2021 *** (No measure applicable)` not like this `*** HEDAL - 2021 COMPLETE - IB - 06-01-2021 (No Measure Applicable) ***`

Comment: So, try `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A9=B2:B9, REGEXREPLACE(A2:A9, "(\*+)$", "(No change) $1"), B2:B9))` then.

Comment: Thank you very much @Wiktor Stribiżew i missed this one just struggling to adjust it in above formula. Sir if it does not bother you can you please look into this question  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827187/creating-a-hyperlink-in-google-sheets-via-formula/67828402#67828402) and please post an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: So, does the above work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following formula to Column C:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A9=B2:B9, REGEXREPLACE(A2:A9, "(\*+)$", "(No Measure Applicable) $1"), B2:B9))
```

This replaces the trailing one or more asterisks with `(No Measure Applicable)` + space + the asterisks captured into Group 1.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew